# AppCompatImageView Different behaviors with Lollipop and below versions

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, android-xml

I'm using this **XML** code,
My Full Xml structure look like:-

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
.....

<ScrollView 
.....
<RelativeLayout 
....
    <View
                android:id="@+id/divider1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detailsPosition"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailsPhoneText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/divider1"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:text="@string/phone" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/detailsPhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/detailsNameOfChaletText"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detailsPhoneText"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/detailsCall"
                android:layout_width="38dp"
                android:layout_height="38dp"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/detailsPhoneText"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/detailsPhone"
                android:layout_below="@+id/divider1"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_call" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/divider2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/detailsCall"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                />

  </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In order to get below view.

On **Marshmallow** and above **versions** it looks okay:-

[image]

But on the **lollipop** and below **versions** it looks like:

[image]

I don't know what's wrong here? How can I reach the right view on all versions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: so, have you made layout-v21/activity_main.xml(for above and 21) and layout/activity_main.xml(API v20 and below)

Comment: @AmitVaghela no it's only one layout.

Comment: please give a try to that and check again

Comment: @AmitVaghela ok, but what the two layout can do for me between i will use the same behaviors and code?

Comment: yes same code..but check https://medium.com/@etiennelawlor/layout-tips-for-pre-and-post-lollipop-bcb2e4cdd6b2

Comment: @AmitVaghela i mean- why using two layout as you suggest may solve the issue?
anyway i used two layout as you suggest but it's the same.

Comment: @AmitVaghela i added full structure for my layout, please have a look.\